# ejs code to display a string variable sent by PostController.js in Sails

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sails.js

Attempting to display a string variable in postview.ejs sent by PostController.js in Sails

val is the string variable

[ ejs html javascript Sails express node.js ]

**PostController.js**

```
module.exports = {

post : function (req, res) {
     var val = req.param('valeur');
     console.log('val =', valeur); // controller test : no problem so far
     res.render('postview')
```

**postview.ejs** (?)

```
  <html>
  <h1>Post view</h1>
  <body>

// until now everything is running smoothly  

  <script type=«text/javascript»>
    document.write ('your value :' + val)
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

ejs code not working : is javascript relevant here ?

What is the correct code in Sails to display val string in the return view ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<%= val %>` if it's EJS.

Comment: EJS runs on the server, you have to remember the brackets to make EJS actually read it and ouput it. `-` means output, and `=` mean output escaped etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to pass the data you want into your view.

```
res.render('postview', {val: val})
```

Then using EJS templates, you would use the following code to render that value `<%= val %>`

Comment: not sure what this means though : " Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience..."

Comment: I'm not sure either. Where and why are you seeing that message?